# Mongoose model as an ES6 class with inheritance chain

Tags: node.js, mongoose, es6-class

I was trying to create a ES6 class hierarchy to implement a caching layer between mongoose and mongodb queries. I saw this PR https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/4668 and based on that wrote the below code.

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://host:port/db", {});
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection failed', arguments));
mongoose.connection.once('open', console.log.bind(console, 'Connected to DB'));

class Base extends mongoose.Model {
    save() {
        console.log('Base class save()')
        return super.save();
    }

    findOne(query){
        console.log('Base class find...');
        return super.findOne(query);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    save(){
        console.log('Derived class save()');
        super.save();
    }

    static getOne(){
        console.log('Derived class Get one');
        return this.findOne({});
    }
}

let usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String })

usersSchema.loadClass(Derived);

let User = mongoose.model(Derived, usersSchema, 'users');

setTimeout(function(){
    User.getOne()
            .then(user => console.log('Found user...', user));

    let newUser = new User();
    console.log('newUser instance of Derived ? ', (newUser instanceof Derived));
    console.log('newUser instance of Base ? ', (newUser instanceof Base));
    newUser.name = 'Tony';
    newUser.save()
                .then(result => console.log('Saved', result));
}, 2000);
```

Since the methods are overridden in the derived class, I was expecting the calls to the methods in Derived class will in turn call the Base class and then I could add additional logic in Base class before / after queries.

Below is the output which I am getting, which indicates that the method invocations are not hitting the Derived/Base class.

**Output**

```
Connected to DB
Derived class Get one
newUser instance of Derived ?  true
newUser instance of Base ?  true
Base class save()
Found user... { _id: 58ec765f9dd99f049c2a833b, name: 'Tony', __v: 0 }
```

When I call the save method, it does not hit the *Derived* class and when I call the getOne static method in *Derived* class, the call does not hit the findOne method in *Base* class. I am not sure where am I going wrong. Can anyone throw some light on this.

Comment: why not use mongoose middlewares?! also an actual use of cache would be great. When storing new data update the cache otherwise deliver cached data it's pretty simple instead of mixing a lot of code into an existing mongoose code.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Phoenix. Thought of using mongoose middleware.. But I couldn't find a way to abort a find query if I get the data from cache. Is there anyway to return the data from middleware instead of calling next()? I have seen the done option too, but I suppose that's applicable only to save hook. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: you can either check the cache before calling mongoose model find or use an middleware and throw an custom error `next(err)` to abort querying.

Comment: I'm having that problem. This is the github [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5227) related [tag:mongoose][tag:es6-class]
<br><br>EDIT: The solution is coming by [him](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3267107/vkarpov15). in this [comment](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5227#issuecomment-304147443) to the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I literally face this issue yesterday.

Here is the code that I got working :

```
class User extends mongoose.Model {
    constructor(user) {
        super(user);
        this.settings = new UserSettings({userId: this._id});
    }

    async save(callback) {
        try {
            await this.settings.save();
            return super.save(callback);
        }
        catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

    //implement only if you want to use create...
    static async create(obj, callback) {
        let user = new User(obj);
        return user.save(callback);
    }
}
```

I think you are missing the `async` keyword, thus having race effects.

I created this code to automatically create sub-documents (with default values) when you create the parent, instead of doing
`let prt = new Parent({}).save()` then (following the docs) : `Parent.find({id: prt.id}).populate('child')`.

This was kinda badly documented, or maybe I missed the right documentation...

Comment: Saw this late. Good to know the async part of it. I am not planning to use the async/await keywords yet. But from an implementation perspective do you see anything wrong in the above approach other than the async part?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you should add a return statement at the Derived save() function.